# why MSVC fails with T<void(ClassName)>?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

namespace SMSpp_di_unipi_it
{

#define SMSpp_insert_in_factory_h                                            \
 static class _init { public:  _init(); } _initializer;                      \
 const std::string & private_name() const;                                   \
 static const std::string & _private_name()

namespace SMSpp_type_traits
{

template< typename T >
struct t;
template< typename T , class U >
struct t< T( U ) >
{
 using type = U;
};
}

inline std::string && SMSpp_classname_normalise( std::string && str ) {
 str.erase( std::remove_if( str.begin() , str.end() , ::isspace ) ,
            str.end() );
 while( str.front() == '(' ) {
  str.pop_back();
  str.erase( 0 , 1 );
 }
 return( std::move( str ) );
}

#define SMSpp_insert_in_factory_cpp_1_t( ClassName )                         \
 template<>                                                                  \
 const std::string &                                                         \
 SMSpp_type_traits::t<void(ClassName)>::type::_private_name( void ) {        \
  static const std::string _name( SMSpp_classname_normalise(                 \
                                              std::string( #ClassName ) ) ); \
  return( _name );                                                           \
  }                                                                          \
                                                                             \
 template<>                                                                  \
 const std::string &                                                         \
 SMSpp_type_traits::t<void(ClassName)>::type::private_name( void ) const {   \
  return( SMSpp_type_traits::t<void(ClassName)>::type::_private_name() );    \
  }                                                                          \

}

using namespace SMSpp_di_unipi_it;
 
template< class T = void , int i = 0 >
class DummyBlockT {
 public:
  DummyBlockT( ) {}
 private:
  SMSpp_insert_in_factory_h;
 };

SMSpp_insert_in_factory_cpp_1_t( ( ( ( ( DummyBlockT< std::pair< double , int > > ) ) ) ) );

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with gcc or clang, everything works well.
But If I try to compile with MSVC, the call:

```
SMSpp_insert_in_factory_cpp_1_t( ( ( ( ( DummyBlockT< std::pair< double , int > > ) ) ) ) );
```

generate this error:

```
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [C:\smspp-project\cmake-build-debug\SMS++\SMS++.vcxproj]
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected [C:\smspp-project\cmake-build-debug\SMS++\SMS++.vcxproj]
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C2039: 'type': is not a member of '`global namespace'' [C:\smspp-project\cmake-build-debug\SMS++\SMS++.vcxproj]
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C3083: '
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C2039: '_private_name': is not a member of '`global namespace'' [C:\smspp-project\cmake-build-debug\SMS++\SMS++.vcxproj]
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [C:\smspp-project\cmake-build-debug\SMS++\SMS++.vcxproj]
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [C:\smspp-project\cmake-build-debug\SMS++\SMS++.vcxproj]
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C2039: 'private_name': is not a member of '`global namespace'' [C:\smspp-project\cmake-build-debug\SMS++\SMS++.vcxproj]
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition [C:\smspp-project\cmake-build-debug\SMS++\SMS++.vcxproj]
C:\smspp-project\SMS++\src\Configuration.cpp(37,1): error C2059: syntax error: '}' [C:\smspp-project\cmake-build-debug\SMS++\SMS++.vcxproj]
. . .
```

How can I fix the problem for MSVC without aliasing the `DummyBlockT< std::pair< double , int > >` using a typedef befor calling `SMSpp_insert_in_factory_cpp_1_t`? Or if there is a way to un-aliasing the typedef in order to static return the exacly name `DummyBlockT< std::pair< double , int > >` and not those of the alias?

Comment: `(void)` function parameters are a prehistoric C-ism that existed back when dinosaurs roamed the Earth, and before the Age Of C++. It does not belong in any C++ code. Try getting rid of all fugly `void` function parameters and see what happens. It wouldn't hurt to get rid of all the macro viruses, either, somehow...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik nothing changed :(

Comment: [Shorter repro](https://godbolt.org/z/qG7GG98GK): `std::function<void( (int) )> f;` MSVC just doesn't like redundant parens in the function type, for some reason.

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug. Adding `typedef DummyBlockT< std::pair< double , int > > thetype_t;` and passing `thetype_t` as the macro's parameter makes it compile on Godbolt.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I **need** that the first part of the macro function returns as std::string exactly `DummyBlockT< std::pair< double , int > >` and not `thetype_t`, if I pass the aliased as parameter `SMSpp_classname_normalise( std::string( #ClassName ) )` it will returns the aliased name as std::string :(

Comment: Maybe something silly [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/YesnKzabK). Basically, use a variadic macro so you don't need to wrap the type name into extra parentheses.  Not tested; in particular, I'm not sure `#__VA_ARGS__` does the right thing.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I thinkwe require stringize macro

Comment: @SamVarshavchik MSVC can't get rid of extra parenthesis.. but it's pretty much same compiler  which doesn't like aliases to function type  `using F = void(T)` in `/permissive-` mode, treating them as a cast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how preprocessor  treats parameter of macro. Macro parameters aren'tC++ tokens, they are prprocessor tokens, som obviously you cannot write

```
SMSpp_insert_in_factory_cpp_1_t(DummyBlockT< std::pair< double, int > >);
```

So you write a wrapper

```
SMSpp_insert_in_factory_cpp_1_t( ( ( ( ( DummyBlockT< std::pair< double , int > > ) ) ) ) );
```

And GCC does something usuual with the only argument marcro - it removes extra parent. MSVC doesn't do that, or removes one extra, so you end up with weird code it cannot parse:

```
SMSpp_type_traits::t<void(( ( ( ( DummyBlockT< std::pair< double , int > > ) ) ) ))>::type::_private_name( void ) {
```

You could do this, but that way you loose name of type.

```
using MyType = DummyBlockT< std::pair< double, int > >;
SMSpp_insert_in_factory_cpp_1_t(MyType);
```

You actually could try to use `boost` library instead to get a pretty name. Or use MSVC work-around:

```
// newer GCC won't accept this. MSVC would
//  #define SMSpp_Stringize_(x) #x
//  #define SMSpp_Stringize(x) SMSpp_Stringize_(x)
// GCC would understand this
//  #define SMSpp_Stringize(...) SMSpp_Stringize_((__VA_ARGS__))
// and correcty this
#define SMSpp_Stringize(...) #__VA_ARGS__
// using  ellipsis to take all preprocessor-tokens
#define SMSpp_insert_in_factory_cpp_1_t( ... )                         \
 template<>                                                                  \
 const std::string &                                                         \
 SMSpp_type_traits::t<void(__VA_ARGS__)>::type::_private_name( void ) {        \
  static const std::string _name( SMSpp_classname_normalise(                 \
                             std::string( SMSpp_Stringize(__VA_ARGS__) ) ) ); \
  return( _name );                                                           \
  }                                                                          \
                                                                             \
 template<>                                                                  \
 const std::string &                                                         \
 SMSpp_type_traits::t<void(__VA_ARGS__)>::type::private_name( void ) const {   \
  return( SMSpp_type_traits::t<void(__VA_ARGS__)>::type::_private_name() );    \
  }  

///...

MSpp_insert_in_factory_cpp_1_t(DummyBlockT< std::pair< double, int > >);
```

Comment: "_so you end up with weird code it cannot parse_": That's not weird code. It is valid syntax. The grammar allows adding any number of redundant parentheses around an (abstract) declarator.

Comment: I also can't reproduce GCC removing parentheses. That shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Swift how? [this](https://godbolt.org/z/WjncYxfKr) is not solving the problem

Comment: @dmeoli you should not use nested paernthsis> I cleared that up.

Comment: @user17732522 MSVC doesn't support that. By way it inteprets grammar, a a pair of parents can surround a expression statement but not a type-specifier (which that expression is in part of context where it denotes an argument-list) or declaration.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie The standard requires support for it. The parentheses are around the _ptr-abstract-declarator_, not the whole _type-id_, nor a _type-specifier_ or a declaration. https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#nt:noptr-abstract-declarator

Comment: @user17732522 what version is that? That's not how 4700-ish versions define that (which MSVC not-fully implements). Also I could read this as something like `T (U::*) (V)` vs `T ((U::*)) (V)`. `(T (U::*) (V))`. OP code generates `SMSpp_type_traits::t<void((((DummyBlockT< std::pair<double,int>>))))>`, which MSVC doesn't parse. If there is bug or quirk in compiler (quirks are typical for that one - a feature not supported "becase it breaks 3rd party libraries used by Microsoft or their codebase") we can't do anything but workaround it. They they don't update compilers retroactively.